# can we use empty parameter with pointer and when?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, parameters, arguments

I need to know how pointer is used and what it returns if USED in function called and has a defined empty parameters with asterisk only like in example (unsigned char *)

```
unsigned char func.name( unsigned char * );
```

So, can we use empty parameter with pointer and when? 
and what shall the argument to be?

Comment: That's not specific to pointers. In a function declaration, you can optionally omit parameter name and leave just the type. `void f(int x);` and `void f(int);` mean the same thing.

Comment: `func.name` - this is not valid function name. Inb4: I know it is most likely just a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can omit the name of an argument any time you want to.  The only downsides to doing so are:

1. If you omit the argument name in the function declaration (i.e. in .h file), it might make the intended purpose of that argument harder for a (human) reader to understand.
2. If you omit the argument name in the function definition (i.e. in the .cpp file), the code in your function body will not be able to refer to that argument.

Comment: In Standard C the parameter name cannot be omitted from the function definition

Comment: Also, it doesn't matter what the type of the argument is.  Pointers, references, values, whatever.

Comment: @M.M Sure about "parameter name cannot be omitted from the function definition"?

Comment: @chux yes, see C11 6.9.1/5 "If the declarator includes a parameter type list, the declaration of each parameter shall include an identifier, except for the special case of a parameter list consisting of a single parameter of type void, in which case there shall not be an identifier"

Comment: @M.M Curious, does compiling `int foo(int, int x) {
  return x;
}` warn/fail on your compiler?  My "gcc -std=c99 -O0 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion" does not.

Comment: @chux Yes , [all versions of gcc on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/1qvrRY) give an error; even without your argument list